# EPPlus - How to add data labels to a line chart

Tags: epplus

I am creating an excel chart with EPPlus 6.3.1. There are two series, each is a simple line chart. One series is plotted on the primary Y Axis and the other series is on the secondary Y. As they stand, they do not have data labels for each point. They plot fine but I need to have the data labels,

```
 Dim ViewsChart As ExcelChart = newWorksheet.Drawings.AddChart("AdStats", eChartType.LineMarkers)
 Dim Views As ExcelChartSerie = ViewsChart.Series.Add("B18:B31")
 Dim InquiriesChart = ViewsChart.PlotArea.ChartTypes.Add(eChartType.LineMarkers)
 Dim Inquiries As ExcelChartSerie = InquiriesChart.Series.Add("C18:C31", "A18:A31")
```

From what I have seen, the chart object should have a datalabels property, but I don't see it in Intellisense. Any suggestions? Thanks!  (VB or C# responses are fine.)